# Call variable from custom function

Tags: r

This would seem to be a straightforward problem but I can't find an answer for it...

**How do I write a function where one of the calls refers to a specific variable name?**

For example, if I have a data frame:

```
data=structure(list(x = 1:10, treatment = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("x", "treatment"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can write a trivial function that adds treatment to the other variable in the data frame but this only works if there is a variable called "treatment" in `d`.

```
ff=function(data,treatment){data+treatment)}
ff(data,data$treatment)
```

This works but I want to set it up so the user doesn't call data$Var in the function.

Comment: ff = function(data, var1, var2) {data[, var1] + data[, var2]} ? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: When I run that I get an error that the variables are not found

Comment: To use @JoshW.'s solution, `var1` and `var2` would need to be passed to the function as character strings, otherwise you'd need `deparse(substitute(var1))`.

Comment: That's because `quote()` returns a symbol and you need a string. Try it with `deparse(substitute())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
ff <- function(data, colname) {
   data + data[[colname]]
}
ff( data, "treatment" )
```

or

```
ff <- function(data, column) {
  colname <- deparse(substitute(column))
  data + data[[colname]]
}
ff( data, treatment )
```

(the later can lead to hard to find bugs if someone tries something like `ff(data, 1:10)`)